# How do I require a password for access to a folder in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication

So I have a .htaccess file, and I have a folder in my site that looks like this:
'../site/control/'

I need to prevent users from accessing this directory unless they enter a password.

Here is what I tried adding...

```
<FilesMatch "\site\control\.(\.php)$">
  Order deny
</FilesMatch>
```

I have 0 php experience, I just need to know what to put into this .htaccess file to block access to anyone who can't enter a set password. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I asked a similar question here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28032/htaccess-and-htpasswd-trouble

Answer (score 2):

This is not php, and has nothing to do with php.

.htaccess files are read by your apache web server.

In addition to deny/allowing access you need to specify where apache will look for users.  Some options are LDAP or an htpasswd file, which can created with this handy tool -- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/htpasswd.html

Then in your file above you need to specify whether all authorized users, or specific ones can access.  -- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html